# Is it generally allowed to send a published paper to another conference but in a different format?

Tags: conference, poster

My paper is accepted for poster presentation for a conference. Is it allowed sent it again to other conferences without withdrawing it from first conference? I am looking for oral presentation.

Comment: Most conferences do not allow this, look for the conferences' dual submission policy.

Comment: @xLeitix: This is only true for CS.

Answer (score 6):

Most computer science conferences do not allow this, look for the conferences' dual submission policy.

Answer (score 5):

Marc Claesen's answer is correct **for computer science**.

In most non-CS fields, there is much greater tolerance for "cross-listing" of talks, because the conferences are not the primary "publication venue" for papers. Therefore it is considered entirely appropriate to give a poster presentation at one conference, and an oral talk at another venue, particularly if the audiences are "non-overlapping." It would be expected, though, that unless the conferences are very close to one another in time, that you would update the presentation somewhat between conferences.

Comment: What's actually forbidden is publishing the same paper more than once. Even in computer science, it is perfectly acceptable to talk about the same paper at more than one conference/workshops, as long as at most one of those events publishes proceedings.